# How to Query Big Data From SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In table `Entries` there are 200w data in `2015-02-18`.

In table `Entries` there are 250w data in `2015-03-18`.

How can I query data from table `Entries`, the string of EntryText has the same in 2015-03-18 but not has the same string in 2015-02-18`?

I used the below statement, but this is very slow:

```
SELECT 
      EntryText 
FROM Entries 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, DateCreated)='2015-03-18'
EXCEPT
SELECT 
      EntryText 
FROM Entries 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, DateCreated)='2015-02-18'
```

Comment: ... if `DateCreated` is 2015-03-18 , then its definitely not 2015-02-18

Comment: sorry , I just only to query EntryText that in 2015-03-18 and not in 2015-02-18

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply use your first query to get your desired result:

```
SELECT 
      EntryText 
FROM Entries 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, DateCreated)='2015-03-18'
```

Comment: sorry , I just only to query EntryText that in 2015-03-18 and not in 2015-02-18

Comment: Then, the above answer satisfies your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add an index to the DateCreated column and include the EntryText column.

Also you can take a look at the query execution plan to understand where the slowness is. Is there a table or index scan they is slowing it down? If so, add the proper index.